# Blazor search results not updating when fired from input event

Tags: c#, blazor, debouncing

The goal is to populate a list with search results. The search results should get updated automatically as a user types in the search box.

The problem: the HTML does not re-render when I fire the InputText's @onkeyup event. While the HTML isn't being re-rendered, the search routine is firing as expected.

Here is a minimal version of my code:

```
@using DebounceThrottle;
@using System.Text.Json;
@using System.Text;
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory

<div>
    <InputText @bind-Value=@searchText @onkeyup=OnInputChanged></InputText>
    <ul>
    @foreach(var result in searchResults) {
        <li>@result</li>
    }
    </ul>
</div>


@code {
    private DebounceDispatcher debounceDispatcher = new(1000);
    private string searchText = "";
    private List<string> searchResults = new();
    private bool shouldRender;

    protected override bool ShouldRender() => shouldRender;

    private void OnInputChanged()
    {
        debounceDispatcher.DebounceAsync(async () =>
        {
            await HandleSearchRequest();
        });
    }

    private async Task HandleSearchRequest() {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
                $"https://localhost:7284/api/search?query={searchText}");
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        searchResults = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<string>>();

        shouldRender = true;
    }
}
```

Bypassing the debounce resulted in the same problem I described above:

```
private async Task OnInputChanged()
{
    await HandleSearchRequest();
}
```

On the other hand, the HTML does update as expected if I trigger the search with a button's onclick event:

```
<button type="button" @onclick=HandleSearchRequest>Search</button>
```

**EDIT: Final Solution**
As per @MrC aka Shaun Curtis's answer, all that I was missing to trigger a UI update was a return from the debounce delegator:

```
private void OnInputChanged()
{
    return debounceDispatcher.DebounceAsync(async () =>
    {
        await HandleSearchRequest();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Polite] You're overcomplicating this.  Wrapping `Tasks` in `Tasks` won't solve the fundamental problem, and manually calling `StateHasChanged` just hides it.

`OnInputChanged`is a UI Event.  `ComponentBase` already has an async wrapper for UI events which expects a `Task`.  It calls `StateHasChanged` if the handler awaits and after the handler completes.

In your code, you return a `void`, so the handler has nothing to `await`.  When your first `await` yields, the UI Handler runs to completion doing the render before you've got the data.  `void` works with a fully synchronous handler because there's no yielding, but adding async behaviour sinks you.

I'm guessing from your code that `debounceDispatcher.DebounceAsync` takes a `Func<Task>` argument, so this should work:

```cs
    private async Task OnInputChanged()
        => await debounceDispatcher.DebounceAsync(HandleSearchRequest);
```

or this, which just passes the `Task` returned by `DebounceAsync` back to the UI Handler.

```cs
    private Task OnInputChanged()
        => debounceDispatcher.DebounceAsync(HandleSearchRequest);
```

The basic rule is this:

```cs
    private async void OnInputChanged()
```

is a **NONO** except in standard (not UI) "fire and forget" event handlers.

**For reference**

This is the `ComponentBase` handler.  It's called by the Renderer.

````cs
```csharp
    Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        var task = callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
        var shouldAwaitTask = task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion &&
            task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

        StateHasChanged();

        return shouldAwaitTask ?
            CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(task) :
            Task.CompletedTask;
    }

   private async Task CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch 
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
                return;

            throw;
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }
````

Answer (score 1):

Calling `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` forces the dom to re-render. Not sure if this the best method but it works for my purposes.

```
private void OnInputChanged()
{
    debounceDispatcher.DebounceAsync(async () =>
    {
        await HandleSearchRequest();
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    });
}
```